# Feature Significance Test for Regression Models e.g. Lasso

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I'm not talking about feature selection here. Imagine you have selected your model (any regression model) and your features and happy with what you have, and you want to do regression. After doing regression then you want to do a significance test on your features to see which one has been more important overall in your regression model.

To my knowledge, there is no command in Scikit-Learn/Tensorflow for doing that, for any of the regression models, please correct me if you know of any. Only for random forest you can get it as below:

```
regr_rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=10, max_depth=max_depth, random_state=10)
regr_rf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
importances = list(regr_rf.feature_importances_)
print("features importance is", importance)
```

So what would be the best way of doing that manually for other regression models? Would like removing features one-by-one and be a way to go?

Comment: This question is better suited to https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, for simple regression models you can just look at the relative sizes of the parameters for an indication of feature importance. The leave-out method you are mentioning is also valid (have even seen it used in scientific articles).